# Running virus from real folder in Sandboxie

Tags: virus, virtualization, sandbox

What if I download a virus to my real folder but only execute it in [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), is it less secure that if I download it directly from SB?

Answer (score 1):

> What if I download a virus to my real folder but only execute it in
>   Sandboxie, is it less secure that if I download it directly from SB?

Simpy downloading a virus should not pose any real threat until it is executed.That goes without saying that it doesn't matter if it is an executable or any other file format.If it is a different file format again as long as you have only downloaded it shouldn't pose any threat.That is of course assuming the browser download function isn't vulnerable in some way.